# Does transforming an upgraded card keep the upgrade?

Tags: slay-the-spire

If I transform an upgraded card into a different card, will the newly transformed card still be upgraded?

[image: Transforming a card]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. When an upgraded card is transformed it will lose the upgrade. This can be seen in the preview window before confirming which card you select, which you can back out of.

[image: transform preview showing upgraded card turning into a non upgraded card]